# Record of oil consumption, past hundred years, recent update?

Tags: data-request, energy

Can anyone point me toward a record of global oil consumption over the past 100 years, up to 2016 or 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The U.S. Energy Information Administration has data on global oil consumption going back to 1980:

https://www.eia.gov/beta/international/?src=-f4

BP publishes an annual statistical review of energy that includes oil consumption. It provides a spreadsheet that goes back to 1965:

https://www.bp.com/en/global/corporate/energy-economics/statistical-review-of-world-energy.html

For anything before that time, you'll probably have to search through old reports or books. For example, I scanned through the UN Statistical Yearbook and found production stats for oil, but not oil consumption (there was consumption data for total energy).

https://unstats.un.org/unsd/publications/statistical-yearbook/past-issues/